# MySQL with C# problems

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I am using MySQL with C#, but i have problems. Why doesn't work this code?

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("myConnectionString");

MySqlParameter lastId = new MySqlParameter();
lastId.ParameterName = "@LastID";
lastId.Value = 0;
lastId.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;


this.Command.Parameters.Add(lastId);
this.Command.CommandText = "SET @LastID = LAST_INSERT_ID();";

// You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
// corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
// to use near '0 = LAST_INSERT_ID()'  
this.Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: How about you tell us why? What doesn't work? What errors do you get? What have you tried to fix the issue?

Comment: For one, @LastID is a parameter you're passing in, but you're trying to set it as a variable.  Like the error says, you're trying to assign a value of LAST_INSERT_ID() to another value of 0.

Comment: What about doing `Select LAST_INSERT_ID()` and `var lastId = Command.ExecuteScalar();`.  No need for an out parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above is simply wrong for many reasons.

- First, a MySqlCommand object needs to be associated with an open
  connection and nowhere in your code there is a connection created,
  opened AND associated with the command
- Second, the command text to retrieve the LAST_INSERT_ID is SELECT
  LAST_INSERT_ID(), no need to have an output parameter for that, but most important, in your code there is no insert command for which you want to retrieve the LAST_INSERT_ID value.
- Third, you don't use ExecuteNonQuery to read back values, in your
  case you could use ExecuteScalar

So

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand());
{
    con.Open();

    // BUILD an unique string with the INSERT INTO 
    // followed by the SELECT (with semicolon to divide)
    string sqlInsertText = @"INSERT INTO yourTable (field1, FieldX) VALUES (value1, ValueX);
                            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
    cmd.CommandText = sqlInsertText;

    // ExecuteScalar will execute the text of the command and returns the first column of the 
    // first row retrieved by the last statement executed 
    // (in this case the result of SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if(result != null)
    {

       int lastID = Convert.ToInt32(result);
       .....
    }
}
```